# bootstrap 3.0 column push to bottom in mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I have this HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="col1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" id="col2"></div>
</div>
```

In mobile view, how can I move `col1` to the bottom, after `col2`. I know it is easy if I move `col1` after `col2` in the DOM, but I want to stay `col1` on the left side and `col2` on right side.

Comment: Could you please post your current CSS to fiddle with?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3 is Mobile first, use in code order of columns which you want to display in mobile view and use `col-xx-push-y` and `col-xx-pull-y` classes to reorder columns in desktop view.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-xs-12">Right column, but first in mobile view</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-12">Left column, displayed in left although it is declared in code after right column</div>
</div>
```

Check demo here - http://www.bootply.com/rZ5Uv8q84K

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a mobile first strategy compiled with bootstrap column ordering technique.

Use the following classes and structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4 col-xs-12" id="col2">Col 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 col-xs-12" id="col1">Col 1</div>
</div>
```

Firstly you order the columns on how you want them to appear on mobile (col 2 first then col 1, etc). Once the view port hits the MD size you want them to stack correctly, to do this you use the col-md-push and col-md-pull to re-order the columns. `Col 1` gets pulled 8 (the size of col 2) and `col 2` gets pushed 4 (the size of col 1).

View demo here: http://www.bootply.com/kHPSKAPgAA

**Additionally** you don't actually need to include col-xs-12 in your columns. After the view port goes bellow the MD size it will automatically reset to 100% (the equivalent of col-xs-12).